# Como ver gráfico de resíduos no R?

Tags: r

Esses são os comandos dados, basicamente:

```
library(psych)
library(readxl)
library(minqa)
library(car)
COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm <- read_excel("COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm.xlsx")
View(COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm)
setwd("C:/Users/Rodolfo Fabriz.ESCRAVo/Desktop/Rodolfo/Mestrado/Econometria")
COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm <- read_excel("COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm.xlsx")
View(COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm)
```

calculando a estatística descritiva e salvando em uma base de dados (questões 1 e 2)

```
summarysComdinheiro <- as.data.frame(describe(COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm))
View(summarysComdinheiro)
```

para gerar arquivo a ser aberto no excel

```
write.csv(summarysComdinheiro, file="descritiva_comdinheiro.csv")
```

attach a base COMDINHEIRO para as próximas questões

```
attach(COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm)
?attach
```

gerando os gráficos de dispersão (questões 3 e 4)

```
?par
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(IBOV,PETR4,main="PETR X IBOV",xlab = "IBOV",ylab = "PETR",pch=19)
?pch
plot(IBOV,PETR4,main="PETR X IBOV",xlab = "IBOV",ylab = "PETR")
plot(IBOV,PETR4,main="PETR X IBOV",xlab = "IBOV",ylab = "PETR",pch=19)
plot(IBOV,CDI,main="CDI X IBOV",xlab = "IBOV",ylab = "CDI",pch=19)
```

calculando correlações
 gerando base de dados, com dados numéricos somente, para uso com a função cor

```
?numeric
?as.data.frame
?data.frame
?data.class
COMDINHEIRO_numeric <- data.frame(PETR4,VALE3,BBAS3,NATU3,IBOV,CDI)
cor(COMDINHEIRO_numeric, use = "complete.obs")
```

arredondando para duas casas decimais

```
round(cor(COMDINHEIRO_numeric, use = "complete.obs"),2)
```

gerando os retornos em excesso ao CDI (questão 5)

```
COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm$petr_exc <- (PETR4-CDI)
COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm$vale_exc <- (VALE3-CDI)
COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm$bbas_exc <- (BBAS3-CDI)
COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm$natu_exc <- (NATU3-CDI)
COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm$ibov_exc <- (IBOV-CDI)
```

Agr quero os valores dos retornos em excesso!

Comment: Esta questão parece ser um dever de casa. Perceba as referências às questões 1 a 5. Além disso, não entendi o que o OP quer dizer por resíduos no caso dele. Em geral, quando falamos de resíduos em estatística, estamos falando da diferença entre o valor observado em um conjunto de dados e o valor previsto por um modelo ajustado a estes dados. Pelo que percebi, o OP não ajustou nenhum modelo aos dados que analisou.

Comment: Para quê postar instruções tais como `?comando`? Uma vá lá, ainda passa, mas tantas...

Comment: Perdão, era pra ver as colunas.

Comment: Acabei usando summary

Comment: ? serve para tirar dúvidas, sou iniciante.

Comment: COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm$petr_capm_res_L <- c(NA,COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm$petr_capm_res[-nrow(COMDINHEIRO_UFESpro_capm)])

Comment: O comando acima não me deu nenhum retorno, poderiam me dizer porque?